# Why are heavy elements used in nuclear power plants?

Tags: energy, nuclear-engineering

I've seen that the energy produced by breaking an oxygen atom's nucleus is equivalent to burning a LOT of coal, 4.6 million metric tons if I remember correctly. (Crash Course Chemistry)

If that is the case, why do people mine for uranium and plutonium for nuclear power plants if lighter elements can produce a tremendous amount of energy? Why can't they use nitrogen, which is abundant in the atmosphere, instead of radioactive elements?